# How to configure log4j.properties file for file appenders in netbeans 6.8?

Tags: java, log4j, netbeans6.8

I am new to log4j and logging activities.

I have log4.properties file.

```
**log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %40.40c:%4L - %m%n**
```

please suggest me how to configure it to log message into my specified file like i want it to log somewhere(i.e c:\abc.log);

let me know if you require some more inforamtion

Answer (score 1):

As a quick answer:

```
log4j.appender.FileAppender= org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FileAppender.File= C:\abc.log
log4j.appender.FileAppender.MaxFileSize= 10MB
log4j.appender.FileAppender.MaxBackupIndex= 10
log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout= org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= \#\#\#\#<%d{MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss aa zzz}> <%p> <%c> <%X{machine}> <%X{wlsDomain}> <%t> <%X{userid}> <%X{object}> <%X{messageCode}> <%X{reqId}> <%X{reqURL}> <%m>%n
log4j.appender.FileAppender.Threshold= DEBUG
```

You could also need to update

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, FileAppender
```

or

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, stdout, FileAppender
```

I'd strongly suggest you to check the documentation.  You seem to be using [log4j 1.x](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) .  If you are using log4j 2.x, you can check [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) .

Comment: I copied this layout, but out file contains log messages in different format than it is visible on console.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple. Try this

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, ROOT
# Direct log messages to a log file
#log4j.appender.ROOTLOGGER=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.ROOT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
# appends the log level to file name abc.log
log4j.appender.ROOT.File=abc.log 
log4j.appender.ROOT.MaxFileSize=1000KB
#Keep 5 old files around.
log4j.appender.ROOT.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.ROOT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#Format almost same as WebSphere's common log format.
# d date, t ist der Name des Threads, M ist Methodenname, C full qualified Classenname 
#log4j.appender.ROOT.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %t %C:%l %-4p - %M%n
log4j.appender.ROOT.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%d] [%t] %l : %m%n
```

Comment: I have also one issue that where to put log4j.xml file.In my case application is using log4j.xml coming from some of the dependency that is not mine log4j.xml its coming from some JAR so i am not able to understand thay why my log4j.xml is not having priority.let me help

Comment: What do you mean here with "my log4j.xml is not having priority"?

Comment: it means in root application whre i have customized log4j.xml file.but it is not displyed after buld war of that application.after build jar,log4j.xml that is displayed is different i think it is coming from external JAR that i have externally added in my root application

Comment: if you are using log4.xml you have the possibility to define which what you want to log or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=error, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Struts2
log4j.logger.freemarker=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2.components=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2.dispatcher=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2.convention=ERROR

# Alfresco
log4j.logger.org.alfresco=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.ws=ERROR
```