# unable to create a log file using log4j

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, apache-axis, tomcat6

I have created a webservice in eclipse using axis2. I have configured the log4.properties file as below

```
og4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE, LOGFILE
# Set the enterprise logger priority to FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.enterprise=FATAL
log4j.logger.de.hunsicker.jalopy.io=FATAL
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=FATAL
log4j.logger.com.ws.webservice=TRACE, LOGFILE
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.wire=DEBUG, LOGFILE
log4j.logger.httpclient= DEBUG, CONSOLE, LOGFILE
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=DEBUG, CONSOLE, LOGFILE

# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %m%n
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger 

# LOGFILE is set to be a File appender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=axis2.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

I have overridden default implementation of axis2 logging like this:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
```

Also fixed the JVM arguments to get the log4jproperties from a specific location:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:E:\Workspace\eclipse-workspace\WS\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.properties
```

Imported the required jar file as well:

- log4j-1.2.17.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
- slf4j-jdk14-1.7.10.jar

I have tried everything possible, but still I am not able to generate a log file. It only prints to console

Below is the text printing to console:

```
[DEBUG] getAction (null) from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@6397593b
[DEBUG] Old SoapAction is (null)
[DEBUG] New SoapAction is ()
[DEBUG] setAction Old action is (null)
[DEBUG] setAction New action is ()
[DEBUG] Input contentType (text/xml;charset=UTF-8)
[DEBUG] CharSetEncoding from content-type (UTF-8)
[DEBUG] createSOAPEnvelope using Builder (class org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder) selected from type (text/xml)
[DEBUG] char set encoding set from default =UTF-8
[DEBUG] XMLStreamReader is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamReaderWrapper
[DEBUG] Starting to process SOAP 1.1 message
[DEBUG] Build the OMElement Envelope by the StaxSOAPModelBuilder
[DEBUG] Build the OMElement Header by the StaxSOAPModelBuilder
[DEBUG] Build the OMElement Body by the StaxSOAPModelBuilder
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking pre-condition for Phase "Transport"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking phase "Transport"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking Handler 'RequestURIBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Transport'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking for Service using target endpoint address : http://localhost:2020/Wataniya_WS/services/Wataniya_WebService/
[DEBUG] org.apache.axis2.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(servicefound)
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Found AxisService : Wataniya_WebService
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking Handler 'SOAPActionBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Transport'
[DEBUG] getAction () from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@6397593b
[DEBUG] SoapAction is ()
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking for Operation using Action : 
[DEBUG] getOperationBySOAPAction:  is null or ''. Returning null.
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking post-conditions for phase "Transport"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking pre-condition for Phase "Addressing"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking phase "Addressing"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking Handler 'AddressingInHandler' in Phase 'Addressing'
[DEBUG] No headers present corresponding to http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing
[DEBUG] No headers present corresponding to http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking Handler 'AddressingBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Addressing'
[DEBUG] getAction () from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@6397593b
[DEBUG] SoapAction is ()
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking for Operation using Action : 
[DEBUG] getOperationBySOAPAction:  is null or ''. Returning null.
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking post-conditions for phase "Addressing"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking pre-condition for Phase "Security"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking phase "Security"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking post-conditions for phase "Security"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking pre-condition for Phase "PreDispatch"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking phase "PreDispatch"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking post-conditions for phase "PreDispatch"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking pre-condition for Phase "Dispatch"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking phase "Dispatch"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking Handler 'RequestURIBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking Handler 'SOAPActionBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] getAction () from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@6397593b
[DEBUG] SoapAction is ()
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking for Operation using Action : 
[DEBUG] getOperationBySOAPAction:  is null or ''. Returning null.
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking Handler 'RequestURIOperationDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Attempted to check for Operation using target endpoint URI, but the operation fragment was missing
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking Handler 'SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] Build the OMElement generateBillProcessPDF by the StaxSOAPModelBuilder
[DEBUG] org.apache.axis2.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(operationfound)
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Found AxisOperation : generateBillProcessPDF
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking Handler 'AddressingValidationHandler' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] getAddressingRequirementParemeterValue: value: 'null'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking Handler 'HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking Handler 'GenericProviderDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking Handler 'MustUnderstandValidationDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] JAXWS MustUnderstandValidationDispatcher.invoke on AxisService Wataniya_WebService; AxisOperation org.apache.axis2.description.InOutAxisOperation@5bb20c47
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking post-conditions for phase "Dispatch"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] isReplyRedirected: ReplyTo is null. Returning false
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking pre-condition for Phase "RMPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking phase "RMPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking post-conditions for phase "RMPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking pre-condition for Phase "OperationInPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking phase "OperationInPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking Handler 'MustUnderstandChecker' in Phase 'OperationInPhase'
[DEBUG] Building list of understood headers for all operations under Wataniya_WebService
[DEBUG] Parameter not on Wataniya_WebService; org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.EndpointDescription.handlerParameterQNames
[DEBUG] Adding headers from SOAP handlers; headers = null
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking post-conditions for phase "OperationInPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking pre-condition for Phase "soapmonitorPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking phase "soapmonitorPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking post-conditions for phase "soapmonitorPhase"
[DEBUG] getAction (null) from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@65636391
[DEBUG] Old WSAAction is (null)
[DEBUG] New WSAAction is (http://Wataniya.com/Wataniya/generateBillProcessPDFResponse)
[DEBUG] setAction Old action is (null)
[DEBUG] setAction New action is (http://Wataniya.com/Wataniya/generateBillProcessPDFResponse)
[DEBUG] messageID is null.
Apr 08, 2015 1:20:34 PM com.wataniya.Wataniya_WebServiceSkeleton generateBillProcessPDF
INFO: 1428479434057Method : generateBillProcessPDF
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Kiriti_Share (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.wataniya.Wataniya_WebServiceSkeleton.generateBillProcessPDF(Wataniya_WebServiceSkeleton.java:426)
    at com.wataniya.Wataniya_WebServiceMessageReceiverInOut.invokeBusinessLogic(Wataniya_WebServiceMessageReceiverInOut.java:147)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Apr 08, 2015 1:20:34 PM com.wataniya.Wataniya_WebServiceSkeleton generateBillProcessPDF
SEVERE: 1428479434059java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Kiriti_Share (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.wataniya.Wataniya_WebServiceSkeleton.generateBillProcessPDF(Wataniya_WebServiceSkeleton.java:426)
    at com.wataniya.Wataniya_WebServiceMessageReceiverInOut.invokeBusinessLogic(Wataniya_WebServiceMessageReceiverInOut.java:147)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking pre-condition for Phase "soapmonitorPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking phase "soapmonitorPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking post-conditions for phase "soapmonitorPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking pre-condition for Phase "OperationOutPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking phase "OperationOutPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking post-conditions for phase "OperationOutPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking pre-condition for Phase "RMPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking phase "RMPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking post-conditions for phase "RMPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking pre-condition for Phase "PolicyDetermination"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking phase "PolicyDetermination"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking post-conditions for phase "PolicyDetermination"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking pre-condition for Phase "MessageOut"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking phase "MessageOut"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking Handler 'AddressingOutHandler' in Phase 'MessageOut'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking post-conditions for phase "MessageOut"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking pre-condition for Phase "Security"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking phase "Security"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Checking post-conditions for phase "Security"
[DEBUG] getAction (http://Wataniya.com/Wataniya/generateBillProcessPDFResponse) from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@65636391
[DEBUG] SoapAction is (http://Wataniya.com/Wataniya/generateBillProcessPDFResponse)
[DEBUG] SOAP Action from messageContext : (http://Wataniya.com/Wataniya/generateBillProcessPDFResponse)
[DEBUG] Start getContentType: OMOutputFormat [ mimeBoundary =null rootContentId=null doOptimize=false doingSWA=false isSOAP11=true charSetEncoding=UTF-8 xmlVersion=null contentType=null ignoreXmlDeclaration=false autoCloseWriter=true actionProperty=null optimizedThreshold=0]
[DEBUG] getContentType= {text/xml}   OMOutputFormat [ mimeBoundary =null rootContentId=null doOptimize=false doingSWA=false isSOAP11=true charSetEncoding=UTF-8 xmlVersion=null contentType=text/xml ignoreXmlDeclaration=false autoCloseWriter=true actionProperty=null optimizedThreshold=0]
[DEBUG] contentType from the OMOutputFormat =text/xml
[DEBUG] contentType returned =text/xml; charset=UTF-8
[DEBUG] start writeTo()
[DEBUG]   preserve=false
[DEBUG]   isOptimized=false
[DEBUG]   isDoingSWA=false
[DEBUG] Creating MTOMXMLStreamWriter
[DEBUG] OutputStream =class java.io.BufferedOutputStream
[DEBUG] OMFormat = OMOutputFormat [ mimeBoundary =null rootContentId=null doOptimize=false doingSWA=false isSOAP11=true charSetEncoding=UTF-8 xmlVersion=null contentType=text/xml ignoreXmlDeclaration=false autoCloseWriter=true actionProperty=null optimizedThreshold=0]
[DEBUG] preserveAttachments = false
[DEBUG] XMLStreamWriter is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamWriterWrapper
[DEBUG] Calling MTOMXMLStreamWriter.flush
[DEBUG] Could not close builder or parser due to:
[DEBUG] builder is null
[DEBUG] Calling MTOMXMLStreamWriter.flush
[DEBUG] close
[DEBUG] end writeTo()
[DEBUG] Found RequestResponseTransport setting response written
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "Security"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "MessageOut"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'AddressingOutHandler' in Phase 'MessageOut'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "PolicyDetermination"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "RMPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "OperationOutPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=91e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "soapmonitorPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "soapmonitorPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "OperationInPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'MustUnderstandChecker' in Phase 'OperationInPhase'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "RMPhase"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "Dispatch"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'MustUnderstandValidationDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'GenericProviderDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'AddressingValidationHandler' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'RequestURIOperationDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'SOAPActionBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'RequestURIBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "PreDispatch"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "Security"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "Addressing"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'AddressingBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Addressing'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'AddressingInHandler' in Phase 'Addressing'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "Transport"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'SOAPActionBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Transport'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=81e3158865f91008e5101b82d34b12df67084d3c8870cfb4] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'RequestURIBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Transport'
[DEBUG] Found RequestResponseTransport returning isResponseWritten()
[DEBUG] Entering deleteAttachments()
[DEBUG] Exiting deleteAttachments()
```

Comment: lets try something log4j.appender.FileAppender.File= C:\axis2.log

Comment: Ok let me try. Will update you

Comment: actually lets check this out. you may find something on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374223/how-to-configure-log4j-properties-file-for-file-appenders-in-netbeans-6-8

Comment: Still printing it to console when I tried the same from the link

Comment: @newuserua Updated the question with console output printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made properties file look simple. Updated the log4j.properties file to:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=E:\\Workspace\\eclipse-workspace\\Wataniya_WS\\logs\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Can you explain what you changed and why this works?

Comment: I just update this "log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout" and successful generate log. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

provide full path  in

log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=/home/xyz/Abc/axis2.txt

instead of

log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=axis2.log

Comment: Updated the question with console output printed